# How can I export only the opcodes from objdump (or any other program)

Tags: malware, objdump, assembly

I have multiple malware files, I want to do an analysis with the opcodes. Im able to export everything to text but I only need the middle column. Any idea on how can I solve this?

In other words of this output of objdump (objdump -d file)

[image]

how can I only extract: 
8d 36
8d 3f
55
90
90
8d 36
89 e5
8d 36

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract all the opcode you can try to run this command:

```
objdump -d ./your_program|grep '[0-9a-f]:'|grep -v 'file'|cut -f2 -d:|cut -f1-6 -d' '|tr -s ' '|tr '\t' ' '|sed 's/ $//g'|paste -d '' -s |sed 's/^/"/'|sed 's/$/"/g'
```

If you need a shellcode format (\x8d\x36\x8d...), you can use this command:

```
objdump -d ./your_program|grep '[0-9a-f]:'|grep -v 'file'|cut -f2 -d:|cut -f1-6 -d' '|tr -s ' '|tr '\t' ' '|sed 's/ $//g'|sed 's/ /\\x/g'|paste -d '' -s |sed 's/^/"/'|sed 's/$/"/g'
```

Take a look at this [page](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/6051/get-all-shellcode-on-binary-file-from-objdump)

Comment: You can tell `cut` to split on tabs in Bash using (the Bash-specific) [ANSI-C quoted strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html): `cut -d$'\t' -f2`

Answer (score 2):

you can use the multiple spaces pattern to rip the opcodes out

```
$ objdump -d c:/windows/system32/calc.exe | sed s/.*:[[:space:]]//g | sed s/[[:space:]][[:space:]].*//g | head -n 10

Disassembly of section .text:

01001000 <.text>:
68 04 82 73 08
57
88 73 29

~$ objdump -d c:/windows/system32/calc.exe | head -n 10

c:/windows/system32/calc.exe:     file format pei-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

01001000 <.text>:
 1001000:       68 04 82 73 08          push   $0x8738204
 1001005:       57                      push   %edi
 1001006:       88 73 29                mov    %dh,0x29(%ebx)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works best for me (and looks easier to understand IMO)

```
objdump -r -j .text -d test | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d$'\t' -f 2
```

shellcode is best extracted via

```
hexdump -v -e '"\\""x" 1/1 "%02x" ""' test
```